# error 2465 can't find field '|1' referred to in your expression

Tags: ms-access, vba, runtime-error, ms-access-2010

I created a query of what I want. I then looked at the SQL View window in Access to copy/paste into VBA. The only thing I changed is the "WHERE" section to include an AutoNumber ID (here referenced as num_PM which is a textbox in a form) I've looked at this for a while and I can't see what I am doing wrong. I am now getting a

> error 2465 can't find the field '|1' referred to in your expression.

```
Set rst_UnitEntryCounts = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT tbl_UnitTypes.UnitTypes_WeeklyTextBoxUserEntryForm, " _
                                                    & "        tbl_UnitTypes.UnitTypes_CumalativeTextBoxUserEntryForm, " _
                                                    & "        tbl_PMEntry.PMEntry_Week_Ending, " _
                                                    & "        Sum(tbl_UnitEntry.UnitEntry_Unit_Count) AS SumOfUnitEntry_Unit_Count " _
                                                    & "FROM (tbl_UnitTypes " _
                                                    & "         INNER JOIN tbl_UnitEntry ON tbl_UnitTypes.UnitTypes_ID = tbl_UnitEntry.UnitEntry_UnitTypes_ID) " _
                                                    & "         INNER JOIN (tbl_PMHeader INNER JOIN tbl_PMEntry ON tbl_PMHeader.PMHeader_ID = tbl_PMEntry.PMEntry_PMHeader_ID) ON tbl_UnitEntry.UnitEntry_PMEntry_ID = tbl_PMEntry.PMEntry_PMHeader_ID " _
                                                    & "WHERE ((tbl_PMHeader.PMHeader_ID) = " & num_PM & " )" _
                                                    & "GROUP BY tbl_UnitTypes.UnitTypes_WeeklyTextBoxUserEntryForm, " _
                                                    & "          tbl_UnitTypes.UnitTypes_CumalativeTextBoxUserEntryForm, " _
                                                    & "          tbl_PMEntry.PMEntry_Week_Ending")
```

Comment: try to Debug.Print the sql statement to check the value of num_PM

Comment: Im new to access/vba. Do I just type this in the VBA window? or the immediate window?

Comment: it should be on vba. since you need the reference on num_PM e.g. `Debug.Print "SELECT.... "`.

Comment: Thank you, I did print out what I was expecting (an autonumber id): See partial code below:

`WHERE ((tbl_PMHeader.PMHeader_ID) = 802 ) GROUP BY tbl_UnitTypes.UnitTypes_WeeklyTextBoxUserEntryForm, tbl_UnitTypes.UnitTypes_CumalativeTextBoxUserEntryForm, tbl_PMEntry.PMEntry_Week_Ending` ...

Comment: did you solved your issue?

Comment: This looks very similar to your unanswered question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460488/use-text-from-record-to-paste-into-an-access-form-controlbox - comments were same for that one - Assign your sql to a variable - and use Debug.Print to print the actual SQL to the Immediate Window - then copy/paste into your question - or to troubleshoot yourself - paste it into a SQL query window to debug

Comment: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418960/managing-and-debugging-sql-queries-in-ms-access/1099570#1099570)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You statement is simply missing a required space character.

Here's the issue:

```
& "WHERE ((tbl_PMHeader.PMHeader_ID) = " & num_PM & " )" _
& "GROUP BY tbl_UnitTypes.UnitTypes_WeeklyTextBoxUserEntryForm, " _
```

`)GROUP` doesn't refer to anything... solution:

```
& "WHERE ((tbl_PMHeader.PMHeader_ID) = " & num_PM & ") " _
& "GROUP BY tbl_UnitTypes.UnitTypes_WeeklyTextBoxUserEntryForm, " _
```

This is assuming that you haven't made any field name spelling errors. I notice that you have a field called `UnitTypes_CumalativeTextBoxUserEntryForm` where the correct spelling is `cumulative` but as long as you've been consistent that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: no problem! If it worked, please mark answer as correct